# Total completion time of the stage is incorrect in Jenkins pipeline using Blueocean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-blueocean

How can I display the total value of all actions taken place within the stage? Inside the stage, git clones happen one after the other.

[image]